# Undefined offset when removing input field that is not the last one

Tags: php, jquery, html, input, cakephp-3.x

I am using this HTML and JQuery code to add input fields:

https://www.sanwebe.com/2013/03/addremove-input-fields-dynamically-with-jquery

with a few changes, my code resembles this, shortened:

`$(wrapper).append('<?php echo $this->Form->input("ticket.' +index+ '.startdate"); ?>');`

where `index` is a var that I'm incrementing and decrementing when the `add field`  or `remove field` buttons are being selected.

The problem is when I remove an element that is not the last one, for example:

[image]

I remove text 1, 2, or 3 and then submit it, I get the `Undefined offset` error, naturally, since the `index` var of the created elements stays the same, and the server gets

`ticket.0.startdate`

`ticket.2.startdate`

`ticket.3.startdate`

and has no idea where the `ticket.1.startdate` is.

PHP code:

```
$festivalticket = $this->Festivaltickets->newEntity();
        if ($this->request->is('post')) {
            $festivalticket = $this->Festivaltickets->patchEntity($festivalticket, $this->request->data, [
                'associated' => [
                    'Tickets'
                ]
            ]);
        }
```

I want to know if there's a way to get past this.

Thank you.

Comment: Don't do it like that.  Show the PHP.

Comment: PHP code is a mess. I'll show the part that matters.

Answer (score 1):

Us an array for your form fields. `ticket_startdate[]` will dynamically append array elements, so something like:

```
$(wrapper).append('<?php echo $this->Form->input("ticket_startdate[]"); ?>');
```

Then just loop through without worrying about the index:

```
foreach($_POST['ticket_startdate'] as $key => $start_date) {
    echo "index $key is $start_date";
}
```

I can't tell what's going on with the PHP you posted.  It looks like a framework so it may handle the array correctly.

Comment: Looks like a good solution, tho I was trying to avoid handling it back in the server.

Comment: That solution works, but looks like I will have to be changing both controller and view whenever I add another field to my table.